# How to make query in blazor to get last ID from table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want get the last id from table. I'm using component blazor and i try do this:

```
int lastID = dl.db.myTable.FromSqlRaw("SELECT MAX(Id) FROM myTable");
```

I got the error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Linq.IQueryable<myTable>'` to `'int'`

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: `FromSqlRaw` returns a collection of results.

Comment: @gunr2171 how can i get only one result?

Comment: There should be a First... method after running FromSqlRaw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Linq

```
db.myTable.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I make var  last= db.myTable.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault(); and to get last ID i make last.Id

Comment: @MarcoOliveira yes, nice!

Answer (score 0):

Your statement will return IQueryable and you can not store it into int datatype, so you can use

```
var list = dl.db.myTable.FromSqlRaw("SELECT MAX(Id) FROM myTable");
int lastID = list.FirstOrDefault().Value
```